# What's the fastest way to mutate a single object property inside a large array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, redux, react-redux

I'm creating a Reddit-like voting system in my application. Each object (thread) has a score property and an array of objects similar to the parent object (think of it as comments to a thread).
Here is a simplified example:

```
{
  id: '123fdx12c1',
  author: 'Anon',
  score: 1,
  users: [
    {
      id: '321fdx12c1',
      name: 'anon',
      score: 1
    },
    {
      id: 'asd123f1fd1',
      name: 'anon',
      score: 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Now imagine a large array of objects like this one. Whenever user votes, an action with proper id is dispatched to look for the matching id and change the score value.
My approach:

```
case 'VOTE':
  return state.map((question) => {
    question.users = question.users.map((user) => {
      if (user.id == action.id) {
        return {
          ...user,
          voteStatus: action.voteStatus,
          score: action.score
        }
      }
      return user;
    });
    if (question.id == action.id) {
      return {
        ...question,
        voteStatus: action.voteStatus,
        score: action.score
      }
    }
    return question;
  });
```

It maps the entire array just to change one property of an object. Is there a faster approach to this?

Comment: Of course there is, you just change the property `state.users[id].score = 'something else'`

Comment: @adeneo it looks like `state.users` is an array not an object.

Comment: Yeah, use a proper database instead of holding state in memory. Database queries are optimized to be fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastest is id lookup, so that finding item by id is almost the same constant time even for a lot of ids:

```
{
    '123fdx12c1' : {
        author: 'Anon',
        score: 1,
        users: [ '321fdx12c1', 'asd123f1fd1' ]
    },
    '321fdx12c1' : {
        name: 'anon',
        score: 1
    },
    'asd123f1fd1' : {
        name: 'anon',
        score: 1
    }
}
```

As a side note, in general function calls in interpreted languages are slower than native code.
In some browsers `.map` can be about 10-100 times slower than for loop.

Comment: That would mean we could mutate the objects like so: state.actionID.score = action.score. Neat, I would definitely use that for a bigger project or if I used actual database instead of local storage.

Answer (score 0):

I know `.map` and `.filter` are popular for various (mostly good) reasons. But sometimes old fashioned for loops are worth using because they are base language, and they have no extra overhead besides what you add in yourself:

```
case 'VOTE':
    var updated = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
        if (state[i].id === action.id) {
            state[i].score += action.score; // or whatever
            break;
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < state[i].users.length; j++) {
            if (state[i].users[j].id === action.id) {
                state[i].users[j].score += action.score; // or whatever
                updated = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (updated) { break; }
    }
```

Notice we get to stop searching the moment we find a match, and nothing has to copied to a new array.

Searching through the whole array may feel like a heavy operation, but make no mistake, `.map` is also doing that under the hood.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer so far and much faster than mine. I thought JS had some built-in tools for doing so. Also, I could get the ID of the superobject first (in order to vote on comments, the superobject/thread must be opened) before searching for the actual ID. That should speed things up: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/758012809302ea02058cc15033585553

Comment: This is a bad approach for React+Redux. You are **directly mutating the existing state values**, which will cause connected components to not re-render.  Immutable updates are needed because they result in new references, and `connect` relies on reference equality checks to detect changes and cause re-renders.  Please see the [FAQ: Components Not Re-Rendering](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-not-rerendering) and [Immutable Update Patterns](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html) section in the Redux docs for more details.

Comment: So what you are saying is: I should make a copy of the original array first then directly mutate its value I want to change and return it as the new original so the Redux engine will compare my current state with the new one it was given and see if they differ?

Comment: @markerikson Looks like I was wrong according to the second article (Common Mistake #2). Does that mean the original solution I provided was correct? If so, is there a better/faster way while also being Redux compatible?

Comment: Yes, the original approach listed in the question looks fine. If you know the index of the item, you could also do something like: `const newArray = oldArray.slice(); newArray[index] = {...newArray[index], {newValue : 42} }`.

Comment: Two other thoughts. First, this is one of the reasons why we encourage the use of [normalized state](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html). Also, there are dozens of existing immutable update utilities available that can abstract out the process of safely updating nested state - see the [Immutable Data#Immutable Update Utilities](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/immutable-data.md#immutable-update-utilities) section of my [Redux addons catalog](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links) for a list.

Answer (score 0):

Get the question from the questions array :

```
const question = state.find(question => (question.id === action.id));
// do something with question
```

then find that user and update its score :

```
const user = question && question.users.find(user => (user.id === action.id));
// do something with user
```

Comment: I think the `action.id` can match the id of either the parent object or a user in one of the parent-objects' `users` array.

Comment: @arbuthnott The above statement will search a user from an array. As for the parent `question` there can be another `find` to fetch the question.

Comment: @arbuthnott correct, the id corresponds to either the parent (thread) or one of the users (comments)

Comment: @Fawaz if I read the question right, you may have to find the matching user subobject without knowing the id of the superobject it belongs to.

Comment: @arbuthnott I agree. In that case it would have to loop through every question. Though it's a weird structure for the data.

Comment: @Fawaz I want to mutate the original array, the solution you provided mutates the copy of an object

Comment: @jwm0 Have you tried that ? it should actually mutate the original object.

Comment: @Fawaz find method does not mutate the original array, it returns either undefined or first element in the array that satisfies the equation

Comment: @jwm0 After you get the object from `find` then you can mutate it or update its values and the changes would reflect in the parent object as well. Hope i'm clear.